# Webpacker won't install in app. Yarn is installed but not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-5, webpacker, yarn-v2

New rails app with webpacker and all dependencies (I think?) up to date.

`rails new app_name -j webpack`

webpack depndencies up to date:

`~ node -v v16.15.1`

`~ yarn -v 1.22.19`

with webpacker in my gemfile

`rails webpacker:install` gives error:

`can't find executable yarn for gem yarn. yarn is not currently included in the bundle, perhaps you meant to add it to your Gemfile?`

Does it mean add yarn to my gemfile? That's weird right?

also `yarn build --watch`

returns an exit code 127

and `rails s` returns `Webpacker configuration file not found`

So I need webpacker to install and all will be good I think but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Read the guides and followed them easily - they aren't complicated but not luck. Can't find anyone else with this problem.